# R:V3.1.1, Platform:x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit), Package: choroplethrMaps

Tags: r, choropleth, choroplethr

This is my first question to the community. I've read through the guidelines and am doing my best to ask an appropriate question and including a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. That being said, please feel free to suggest ways in which I can ask better questions going forward.

I am having trouble with the choroplethrMaps package, which I have never used in the past. I have had issues installing packages on my work computer before, but have gotten around this issue by pasting the package and its dependencies in my library directory. Part of my issues may stem from that, but I'm not sure.

Here is the code that replicates the issue on my machine.

```
library(choroplethrMaps)
library(choroplethrAdmin1)
library(choroplethr)

data(state.map)
df<-data.frame(region=unique(x = state.map$region),value=rnorm(n = 51,mean = 500,sd = 45))
debug(state_choropleth)
state_choropleth(df = df,title = "", legend = "", num_colors = 1)
```

After debugging the state_choropleth function, it looks like there is an error with the "render" portion of the code. When I execute the above code, I get the following error message.

```
Error in withCallingHandlers(tryCatch(evalq((function (..., call. = TRUE,  :
object '.rcpp_warning_recorder' not found
```

Note that I am only using state_choropleth because when running the choroplethr function, I was advised to use state_choropleth instead. It seems as though choroplethr is out of date.

Comment: Very likely it is related to your unusual and not clean installation. What kind of errors you got installing the package in the usual way?

Comment: Hi Nicola. The packages get moved to a temporary folder rather than my R library. I'll double check to make sure all the dependent packages installed.

Comment: The error is suggesting that you have not installed the Rcpp package. Have you looked at all the Installation instructions and DESCRIPTION files of the packages you have installed? If you are having problems with access to the default location of your package library then use `.libPaths` to create a second library (.i.e. a directory that R will search when needing a package resource.) You should also update to a more recent version of R.

Comment: Thank you so much that was it! I thought I had read and installed all the required packages, which i found here [link] (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/choroplethr/index.html)

Comment: I didn't see Rcpp listed so I didn't install it. Is there someplace else I should look to find the required packages? Also thank you for the .libPaths tip. I'm sure that will help me avoid a lot of trouble going forward! Thanks again!